# Is real-time communication possible with a react front-end and C++ executable

Tags: c++, reactjs, real-time

I'm working with a biometric kit for a project. The kit has a simple desktop app to just take the biometric data and save the files as an image. But it has a C++ SDK so you can implement your own communication solution. I want to save the data to my back-end server instead of the computer so am thinking to rebuild the desktop app as a web app and write a C++ server to broadcast events (like real-time finger movements etc...) from the kit to the front-end (react) through the browser which will submit it with other form data.

Am not even sure if my idea is possible technically but if it is what would be the best way to broadcast real-time events from my C++ server to the front-end react app? Or should I just build a desktop app and submit the form from there?

Comment: v8 can do quick calls to C++ for you.

Comment: Websockets, server-sent events or just simple polling

Comment: Just to be clear, you have three parts here?  One, written in C++, where the sensor is connected.  One, written in React, where the user interfaces.  And then a "back-end" database server somewhere out on the network?  Do you expect the first two to always run on the same computer?  If someone tries to connect to your C++ sensor server from React running on another computer, would that cause you any security problems?

Comment: @BenVoigt I want my react app to connect to the C++ server that would be installed on the client's machine. I want to keep the connection only to the front end and the C++ server locally through the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use restbed library. That library let you handle and send HTTP request's.
Github link of the library :
https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/documentation/API.md?ysclid=l5v20puzjb198752037

I am using that library and in my opinion, it is very easy to use and understand. Also, restbed supply very good performance compared to others.